# Gem therubyracer 0.12.3 install error in ruby 3.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, therubyracer

I have upgraded ruby to 3.1.2 and while doing 'bundle update' therubyracer gem install error is happening. I have tried with few options available online like installing with v8@3.15 and libv8 but nothing works. Please somebody help me how to resolve this, I'm using macOS 12 monterey

When i followed these steps,

`brew install v8@3.15`

`gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.19' -- --with-system-v8`

`gem install therubyracer -- --with-v8-dir=/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15`

Last step got me this error

[image]

Comment: The error message would be helpful

Comment: I have updated with error message.

Comment: Which mac chip you are using Intel/M1/M2?

Comment: Its using Intel chip

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apple Silicon device, you can switch to [miniracer gem](https://github.com/rubyjs/mini_racer)